# Debug app working but release app not working?

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, build.gradle

Is there any changes that i want to do in gradle file to work the release app properly. I have recently shifted from normal app to androidx. When i have debug the app and run in my phone it's working properly but when i have installed the release app the it's not working so how to fix it ? When i have move my app to android-x then it has requesting me to change the setShiftingMode(false) to setShifting(false) the problem has been occured due to this or not. How i can fix the above issue ?

```
 buildscript {
        repositories {
            maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'}
        }
    
        dependencies {
            classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.8, 0.99.99]'
        }
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 29
    
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.demo"
    
            manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id               : "fa5f9ac7-sdfdf-dfdf-exampleid-6f",
                                    // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                                    onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]
            minSdkVersion 19
            targetSdkVersion 29
            versionCode 5
            versionName "5.1.11"
            testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
        android {
            lintOptions {
                checkReleaseBuilds false
                // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
                // but continue the build even when errors are found:
                abortOnError false
            }
        }
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
       }
    
        buildTypes {
            release {
                debuggable false
                shrinkResources true
                minifyEnabled true
                useProguard true
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    
    }
    
    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.10.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.10.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
        implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
        implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
        implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.0.0'
        annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.0.0'
        implementation 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
        implementation 'com.devbrackets.android:exomedia:4.2.1'
        implementation 'com.daimajia.numberprogressbar:library:1.4@aar'
        debugImplementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:debug-db:1.0.3'
        implementation 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.4.0'
        implementation project(':library')
        implementation('com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.1@aar') {
            transitive = true
        }
        implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.1'
        implementation 'com.github.faruktoptas:FancyShowCaseView:1.0.1'
        implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.15.0, 3.99.99]'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.3.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.4.4'
        implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
        implementation 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:2.+'
        implementation project(':jiaozivideoplayer')
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
```

Comment: Can you describe what exactly is not working? Does the app build, start, crash? If you have a crashlog, post the relevant part in your question.

Comment: When i have installed the debug app in my phone then it's working properly but when I have released the app and installed in my phone it's not working. In my app there is video in recycle view but it's not showing video. But release app not working